# NumPy array mis-shaped dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to numpy and trying to understand how multi-dimensions work.

I have 300 numpy arrays of dimension (280, 190, 3). When I append all these arrays into a list and convert it into a numpy array (I think it's here where I am doing something wrong) I expect its shape to be (300, 280, 190, 3) but all I get is (300, ) as if it is a 1D array.

Could you please tell me what is my wrong step? Any additional information welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Double check the shapes of those 300 arrays.  Getting a 1d array when you expect 4 is caused by a mix of shapes.  What's the 1d array `dtype`?  `object` is another indicator of ragged inputs.  The newest version, 1.19, is now give a warning if this happens.

Comment: @hpaulj you're right there was the following warning:

Comment: @hpaulj 
`VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)`

so i turned my conversion into this `np.asarray(my_list, dtype=object)` and the warning disappeared but the problem persists.

Comment: You still have a ragged array!  Check the shape of all your 300 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the 1d ragged warning case:

```
In [461]: alist = [np.ones((10,5,3)), np.ones((10,5,3)), np.ones((9,5,3))]                           

In [463]: np.array(alist).shape                                                                      
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[463]: (3,)
```

`stack` in the same case produces an error:

```
In [464]: np.stack(alist)                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-464-724d9c1d0554> in <module>
----> 1 np.stack(alist)

<__array_function__ internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    425     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
    426     if len(shapes) != 1:
--> 427         raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
    428 
    429     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1

ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

If shapes all match:

```
In [465]: alist = [np.ones((10,5,3)), np.ones((10,5,3)), np.ones((10,5,3))]                          
In [466]: np.array(alist).shape                                                                      
Out[466]: (3, 10, 5, 3)
In [467]: np.stack(alist).shape                                                                      
Out[467]: (3, 10, 5, 3)
```

To make a 1d object array from a list of equal size arrays, we have to do some extra work:

```
In [468]: arr = np.empty(3,object)                                                                   
In [469]: arr[:] = alist                                                                             
In [470]: arr.shape                                                                                  
Out[470]: (3,)
In [471]: np.array(arr).shape            # np.array doesn't change this                                                                
Out[471]: (3,)
In [472]: np.stack(arr).shape            # stack still works                                                            
Out[472]: (3, 10, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
data1=np.random.random(size=(280, 190, 3))
data2=np.random.random(size=(280, 190, 3))
data1.shape, data2.shape
((280, 190, 3), (280, 190, 3))
np.stack([data1,data2], axis=0).shape
(2, 280, 190, 3)
```

Comment: but you aren't trying to create a 'ragged' array.  The OP is - albeit unintentionally.

Comment: @hpaulj are you calling it a ragged array because all my arrays' shapes are the same? What is the difference between an array of arrays and a ragged array?

Comment: In my experience if I get the `1.19` ragged warning, I also get an error message from `np.stack` about shapes that don't match.

Comment: @hpaulj yep but when I did it her way the error made me understand what the problem was! Sorry I didn't even know what a ragged array is..

Answer (score 0):

Use the numpy stack to stack arrays separately. Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html