# Reshape array size in Python (Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `arr.shape: (416809, )`

which has:

```
arr[0].shape:
(300,)
```

**and I whish to reshape to**: `(416809, 300)`

I was searching at the documentation but I was unable to find a solution.

Any help would be grateful!

Thanx!

Comment: See this SO question just a few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218534/numpy-array-mis-shaped-dimension.  How was your array created?  Do all the component arrays have the same shape?

Comment: Mine is different. I have 416809 arrays of 300 dimensions and I want to make them. (416809, 300) so 2D

Comment: Does `np.stack(arr)` work?

Comment: No, it makes a tuple of: (416809, 300). The tuple has just these 2 integers. Not the numpy arrays

Comment: `(416809, 300)` is the shape tuple, not the array produced by `stack`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I had mistake in my code. So np.stack(arr) works!. Thank you Type it in the answers I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the shape of a `NumPy array` `ndarray`, use the `reshape()` method of `ndarray` or the `numpy.reshape()` function.

> Here is an example for your reference

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(24)

print(a)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]

print(a.shape)
# (24,)

a_4_6 = a.reshape([4, 6])

print(a_4_6)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [18 19 20 21 22 23]]
```

Comment: This works only when the values of the array are just Integers. In my situation the values of the arrays are numpy arrays of size (300, ). So the reshape method wont work like that.